# Elasticsearch. Single index with lots of mapping vs multiple indeces with few mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multitenant application and recently I was requested to add Elasticsearch. Every tenant will have different fields in data stored inside ES. I have two options:

- Single index with mapping created for each field of each tenant
- Index for each tenant with dedicated mapping.

Which implementation will give more efficient storage and better query performance?
Does number of mappings impact search performance?

Thanks

Comment: In the more recent versions of elasticsearch, you can only have one document type per index, which should answer your question fairly neatly :) Relevant article: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

Comment: I didn't spoke about document types. Only index vs mapping for fields

Comment: Are u saying that you want to have a separate index for each tenant?

Comment: @MayankSinghal I'm asking for a better approach between index for tenant and single index with lots of field mappings

Comment: Number of fields and mappings could impact both storage and search performance, you also have a `total_fields` limit, which is `1000` per default. There are a lot of things that could impact performance, index size, number of shards, type of the disk etc. The only way to find what is best in each case is doing some tests.